# Analysis of Null Handling for Max LINQ

Tags: c#, performance, linq, optimization

I did an analysis of some of the most common recommended methods using BenchmarkDotNet

This include

- DefaultIfEmpty
- OrderByDescending
- And Null Check with Any Clause (DetectIfEmpty)

Through BenchmarkDotNet, I was able to get an averaged Computational time as well as a memory allocation.

Here is the overall results:
[image]

The end result was approach was the fastest

```
    public float? DetectIfEmptyMethod()
    {
        var temp = _items
            .Where(x => x.Name == "Test")
            .Select(x=>x.Value);
    
        if (temp != null && temp.Any())
        {
            return temp.Max();
        }
    
        return null;
    }
```

With DefaultIfEmpty being 50% more space efficient than the OrderByDescending Approach:

```
    public float? DefaultIfEmptyMethod()
    {
        var result = _items
            .Where(x => x.Name == "Test")
            .DefaultIfEmpty()
            .Max(x => x != null ? x.Value : null);
    
        return result;
    }
```

I'm wondering. DefaultIfEmpty from what I read produces Joins when implemented in SQL, how does DefaultIfEmpty work when used with IEnumerables in memory? Also, why the major reduction in memory allocation?

Comment: What's your input i. e. what does `_items` look like?  .NET is open-source so you can easily look at the [implementation of `DefaultIfEmpty()`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/971ebdbd0fe335c34d440269af8055c6eea87286/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/DefaultIfEmpty.cs#L11).

Comment: I created a class with properties Name and Value, with Name being a string and Value being a float. I then initialized the item array during construction with 5000 floats using Random.NextDouble(). These were then converted to floors. While constructing the item array, I added the random float to the initializer to create 5000 items each with their own random float.

Comment: Sorry, I mean they were converted to floats. Autocorrect.

Comment: Btw, you can use also use this code: `_items.Max(x=>x.Name=="Test" ? x.Value : null)`

Comment: The extra allocation when you have an `OrderBy` is because *any* sorting algorithm would require space to store the results if it can't modify the original sequence. The extra allocation in your `DetectEmpty` method is because your `Select(x.Value)` requires temporary storage for the value you selected. You'll see if you remove the `Select`,

Comment: That makes sense. And assumed similarly. What I'm not understanding is why DefaultIfEmpty is so inefficient in an otherwise O(n) algorithm. Applied sorting algorithms should be around O(n lg n) and therein theoretically slower. From the open source code provided, it looks like it's iterating upon an enumeration and detecting MoveNext validity, passing booleans and defaults along the way. It appears between an O(1) if it stops at one iteration, and at worst O(n) if it goes through all of them (doesn't make sense there). So why is it so much worse computationally outside memory improvement?

Comment: On my testing with your code above, `DefaultIfEmpty` *is* fastest when it stops at one iteration, consistent with your hypothesis. Bearing in mind, that "one iteration" means the result of the `Where` clause is empty (hence the name, default if empty) - meaning that NONE of your 5,000 items are actually named "Test".

Comment: In the case where ALL of them are named "Test", then everything will go through the `iterator.MoveNext` of `DefaultIfEmpty`, which then goes through a `switch` case, only to eventually call the next layer `MoveNext` of the inner iterator, pretty much doubling the work (or more; every little bit can be costly if you look at it from a micro-benchmarking perspective, which is pretty much what we're doing here).

Comment: It seems that the DefaultIfEmpty approach whole LINQ should have an Algorithmic complexity of O(n) while the OrderByDescending Approach should have an Algorithmic complexity of O(n lg n). I'm wondering if 5000 randomized data points is still not enough to benefit from the increased Algorithmic efficiency.

Comment: I'm also wondering if .NET 8 has significant improvements on the OrderByDescending Method given its frequency, I remember seeing version comparisons suggest massive improvements across multiple LINQ clauses.

Comment: Found a good answer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/orderby-firstordefault-complexity-increase